# Tools for learning ExpressionEngine addon development

Tags: add-on-development, addons

What are the available tools/tutorials for learning to develop ExpressionEngine addons (modules, fields, extensions, plugins and accessories)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following list should get you started:

- [**ExpressionEngine Add-On Development Docs**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/): 
  links to guidelines, reference material, and tutorials for developing Plugins, Modules, and Extensions for ExpressionEngine
- [**ExpressionEngine Add-on Development Recipes**](http://ee-recipes.com/): a collection of articles and tutorials to help you learn how to build ExpressionEngine add-ons
- [**Add-On Development Cheat Sheet**](http://www.putyourlightson.net/add-on-development-cheat-sheet): freely downloadable cheat sheet and Accessory for ExpressionEngine 2.x. Its purpose is to help add-on developers get used to coding for EE 2, speed up development time and increase productivity.
- [**Building an ExpressionEngine Add-on**](http://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/how-to-develop-expressionengine-add-on/): Commercial yes, but an excellent video by well-respected add-on developer @low giving a solid introduction into planning and building an add-on.
- [**Pkg.io**](http://pkg.io/): Package Builder for ExpressionEngine which will quickly generate boilerplate code for all types of ExpressionEngine add-ons. It includes helpful comments in the source and will jump-start development of your custom add-on.
- **[generator-ee-addon](https://github.com/rsanchez/generator-ee-addon)** An ExpressionEngine Add-On generator for [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/). Capable of building modules, plugins, extensions, accessories and fieldtypes.
- **[DevKit for EE 2.0](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/devkit-for-ee-2.0)** Generate a new module skeleton, yaml 2 dbforge code generation and global variables / snippets sync from filesystem.
- **[Channel-Data (objectivehtml)](https://github.com/objectivehtml/channel-data)** A helper class that compiles all the necessary models to easily gather ExpressionEngine channel data. The main benefit of this library is its ability to be dropped into any existing add-on and retrieve channel data extremely easily without having to load all the models.
- [**EE-Add-On-Builder**](https://github.com/lukewilkins/EE-Add-On-Builder) SublimeText plugin to easily build ExpressionEngine Add-Ons.
- [**Open API**](https://github.com/putyourlightson/open-api) - Front-end API for ExpressionEngine that provides authentication and CRUD functionality.