# Module: Facebook functionality on publish Tab?

Tags: custom-fields, module, facebook

I've been banging my head against the wall with this and I have not found an answer.

I am attempting to build an EE application where admin can come in and create a quiz app.  I then need to allow the admin to add the app to their Facebook Page (using FB Graph API calls).

What I'm facing is when to introduce that Facebook functionality. From what I could see looks like I need to create a custom module.

**Module -- Publish Tab**
But what I see looks like only stuff that goes in publish_tabs function are fields.  Does that mean I must create a custom field then?  I would need to allow the user to authenticate the FB App, then give it permissions to manage FB Pages, then *finally* a way to add the entry/quiz to their FB Page.

Is the tab able to do such functionality? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'd want to do this on the Publish Tab. It would be better for the user to save the entry and be presented with your new FB functionality on the subsequent page.

The **[entry_submission_absolute_end](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/content_publish/index.html#entry-submission-absolute-end)** hook is probably what you'll want to use. It gives you access to the following specific to the entry being saved:

```
$entry_id (int) – Entry ID of submitted entry
$meta (array) – Entry’s metadata (channel_id, entry_date, i.e. fields for exp_channel_titles)
$data (array) – Entry’s field data
$view_url (string) – Control Panel URL to view submitted entry
```

You can also find some helpful addon development resource links on this question:
**[Tools for learning ExpressionEngine addon development](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15167/tools-for-learning-expressionengine-addon-development)**

Comment: After looking into this, I think you're right.  Especially because I wont have the entry_id until after the user has saved the entry.  I've been running into brick walls everywhere.

I dont think I can use an extension hook because the FB functionality requires user interaction (auth the app aka going through FB modals) so it can't be done behind the scenes with a hook.

I do however believe I could possibly utilize the view entry page.  Maybe exposing a section that only a certain user level may see.  And utilize that to handle all the FB tie ins.